# create a gulpfile.js with vendor

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, zurb-foundation-6

I want to use Foundation with Magento2 but I am new to node. I installed zurb/foundation with composer and it works if I run `npm start` or `npm watch`. I need to have files in app/design/frontend/package/theme/web.

I created a gulpfile.js to get things work and I try to import the things I need from the vendor directory but something is strange to me.

```
var path = require("path");
var base = path.normalize(__dirname + '/../../../../../../vendor/zurb/foundation/');

var gulp = require("gulp");
```

require("path") works but require("gulp") does not. If I try to make require(base + "gulp") it does not work either.

I do not really understand why. If I install the gulp and other required modules in the same directory, it works but I think that it is not a really good way.

Answer (score 0):

installing gulp globally (npm install -g gulp) will fix your problem but I think you should first understand why your problem is happening.

require uses a relative path from your parent directories to find package.json and node_modules so when you use require("path") that is globally installed from npm but gulp might not be.

try installing gulp in your project with (npm install --save-dev gulp) and see so that the gulpfile.js is either in the same directory with node_modules or in the same parent (regarding if it's the child of another directory on the same level)